# What architecture should I use to build my own multi-tenancy system?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I already have a web app and now i'm trying to introduce a multi-tenancy concept in it. I was wondering how to manage many databases? I presently have a main database that holds a users table, and other impertinent tables for this question. But my main struggle is that I have a league table that has a 'database_name' which I use to set my MySQL connection with depending on the league the user choose.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are using is fine. You can also, for example, just use `league.name` (if league has a name) as the database name, or add some prefix/suffix to the name. I'm not sure if you are choosing one of multiple defined connections or are you changing the connection's database name in the config. I would suggest the second option.

Comment: I am using one of multiple defined connections. Actually, I have 1 connection used for managing the users and another one for the tenants as we call them

Comment: OK, so when the authenticated user is resolved you can get the database name that you need, right? So then you just `config(['database.connections.another-one.database' => $tenantDatabaseName]);`

Comment: Yeah that's actually what I do!! :) I was wondering if it was ok! I needed some people's advice :) thanks